# How to get the URL of the application for Selenium tests running in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to set up selenium integration tests in my asp.net mvc application, and I'm struggling to get the URL of my application to pass to the selenium web driver.  Most tutorials on the subject just hard-code the url, but that won't work for me as these tests need to run on different developer machines.

I've found a number of blog posts on the subject, but they all >7 years old, and don't seem to work with the current version of the tools.  There were some promising-sounding approaches based on invoking a cassini server by dll reference.

Concretely, this is what I'm trying to do.

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("Selenium")]
public class BasicTests : SeleniumTestFixtureBase {
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://thismachine/app/");
    }
}
```

The url will vary based on who's running it.  How do I get the correct one?

Comment: Can you explain why "localhost" wouldn't work?

Comment: @Speedbird186:  localhost is not ideal since the certificate will have been issued for a different domain.  The app won't allow itself to be served on a non-secure connection.  It could be possible to allow it for debugging purposes, but even then, there can be different deployment paths on localhost.

Comment: Will the  location of the web app relative to the test project always be the same?

Comment: @Speedbird186:  We can rely on that being true on disk.  Of course, the test project doesn't have a url.

Comment: Can you not just pass the URL to the test? Maybe read it from some config file that each user would set up on their own machine?